# How to keep the color of text in TextInputLayout same when it is in focused and unfocused state?

Tags: android, android-layout

I wanted to keep the color of text in TEXT INPUT LAYOUT same when it is in focused or unfocused state. When I click on EDIT TEXT(focused state) I see different color and when it is unfocused I see different color.
Code is attached below.

text_with_edit_text.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutlocality_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tv_locality_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/custom_text_appearance">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_locality_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="locality_2"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="custom_text_appearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">normal</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FF5733</item>
    </style>
```

**

- For Instance

** - I am attaching the image below, 
[I want the color of 'Nombre'(text focused at this movement) to remain same when it is not focused. Also note that the color of hint in EditText should not be same as that of 'Nombre'(when it is in unfocused state)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzVrz.png)

Answer (score 1):

**try this my friend**

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutUname"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:theme="@style/MYAppTheme">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edtUname"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:hint="Please Enter User Name"
                            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:theme="@style/MYAppTheme" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutEmail"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:theme="@style/MYAppTheme">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edtEmail"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:hint="Please Enter Email Address"
                            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:theme="@style/MYAppTheme" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**theme for this is**

```
<style name="MYAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

**now change the color as your reqirment**

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I want to make the the color of text in TextInputLayout similar when it is in focused and unfocused state. In your solution color of hint in edit text and unfocused state are same

Comment: i did not understand what are you trying to tell me please expain in breif.

Comment: I have just attached an image in my question. Hope this would help.

Comment: means you want same color of text input layout on focoused or not focoused

Comment: Yes , and this color should not be same as hintColor in Edit Text.

Comment: It is not what I am looking for, hintColor of Edit Text and color of floating label, after unfocused, should not be same. For eg - I want to keep the hintColor of Edit Text = 'Gray' and color of floating label = 'Blue'.

Comment: Please tell me whether you understand, what I am looking for or not.

Answer (score 0):

Hope so this is worked for you:-

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            <!--EditText hint color-->
            <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/default_app_white</item>
           <!-- TextInputLayout text color-->
            <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/default_app_green</item>
            <!-- EditText line color when EditText on-focus-->
            <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/default_app_green</item>
            <!-- EditText line color when EditText  in un-focus-->
            <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/default_app_white</item>
        </style>
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. Please check my updated question, in which I have attached an image to make it clear what I want. Please read the description of image.